# Identifying a bluetooth development device

Tags: bluetooth, identification, usb-device

This is some kind of bluetooth development device and I want to find out if this can be used with BlueLab software suit, but cannot find more details on it
[image]

The main chip is BlueCore BC358

The area in the green box has some kind of logo ( I think it is the logo of CSR, as a similar logo appears on the BC358 chip as well) with some text `DEV-PC-1324C` and `usb391` on the next line (it is a bit hard to make out)

Using the drivers I get in my BlueSuit installation, Windows 7 detects it as `CSR USP<>SPI converter`

I want to see if this can be used with BlueLabs for Bluetooth development or not ( I am a complete beginner with Bluetooth and BlueLabs right now)

Could someone please provide the name of this device and any kind of details on it?

(It was bought online from China, if that helps)

EDIT1:

[image]

Comment: usb pid/vid? those are very helpful

Comment: @Passerby: Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 bucks says its the DEV-SYS-1808-1A based on the shape and ports, minus the case
[image]

> CSR's USB to SPI converter, which is makes it possible to use BlueSite utilities and access SPI debug ports on all csr devices over USB. This device is suitable for pc's and labtops supplied without parallel port.
>
> Features:
>
> - Programs and debugs all CSR ICs
> - Provides SPI interface from PC USB to CSR IC
> - SPI interface runs over CAT5 lead
> - Compatible with CSR Casira development kits
> - CD with drivers and documentation

**It's used for wired reprogramming, but more importantly, Debricking, of CSR modules.**

Comment: Thank you for your help. So this means I probably need to get something else to attach to this module, to get started on the actual bluetooth part? This isn't the actual module with the bluetooth capabilities but only a connector between the module and the computer?

Comment: It's a secondary connector between a computer and a discrete port on the module.

Comment: I just found the data sheet for the BC358 chip, and it says it is the complete bluetooth system with BlueCore's Kalimba DSP: http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-SL4/DSASL0073623.pdf

Comment: If that is the case, how can this device be just a connector for another module? Would the full bluetooth system with DSP be used as a chip in only a connector? Should I be able to develop bluetooth applications on this device without buying another module?

Comment: @user13267 they probably reused an existing IC and base design and wrote new firmware for it. From what I saw, no, this only does usb to spi. Besides, I don't see an antenna.

Comment: The antenna was the first thing I thought about as well. I still haven't figured out how to use this, but when I tried to run DFUBabel.exe that came with BlueSuit, Windows suddenly detected this as a Bluetooth device, and I was able to pair my phone with the computer. It doesn't do anything else though, that is, when I scan from my phone, it does not show this device although the phone is already paired with it. Also, sending file from the computer to phone through bluetooth is not working, but I don't know whether this is due to a driver issue

Comment: Device Manager now shows a `Generic Bluetooth Radio` and `Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator`, under Bluetooth Radio (which I am sure wasn't there before)

Comment: That's because you changed the firmware. But it's still not usable as a Bluetooth device.

Comment: no actually I haven't changed anything. DFUBabel.exe only started a wizard. If I continue to click `Next` on this wizard, it shows me an error box later that says No USB BlueCore modules were found